# Providing services to only nationals (eu country)

Tags: european-union, discrimination

Within the EU, are there any provisions which discuss how businesses should/are allowed to treat customers based on type of residence.

Context: First heard about a shop which was refusing to sell to immigrants from a nearby refugee camp, which obviously (at least in my opinion) was deemed illegal. Now personally I live as an expat in another EU country and got refused services by a telecom provider because I don't have a local nationality or permanent residence (I don't need a permanent residence legally to live, work and pay my taxes here). Personally I just went to another provider, no big deal, but it did got me wondering whether any such things have been touched upon by the EU.

Comment: Anything where moving cash or data (or people) is likely to be regulated.  Companies interpret money laundering rules in different ways as one example and they may require (or think they require) permanent residence. Insurance plays a factor as does security as does credit checking. I assume you didn't delve in to what the problem was specifically with the telecom provider but if you go back and lodge a formal complaint they will provide you with something specific.